# AT91SAM9260EK upgraded kernel from 2.6 to 4.4, Serial port not working

Tags: linux, serial-port, kernel, uart

Admittedly this is big kernel jump. 2.6 had no concept of device tree and I have not yet created device tree for my product. So just default device tree files with older form of UART settings in board files. Kernel comes up without UART, I think, because the nothing happens after "Starting Kernel ...".

Any input is highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
U-Boot> setenv linux1 'tftpboot 20cfffc0 kernel.latest'
U-Boot>
U-Boot> setenv linux2 'tftpboot 206fffc0 initrd.latest'
U-Boot>
U-Boot> setenv linux3 'bootm 20cfffc0'
U-Boot>
U-Boot> setenv bootlinux 'run linux1 linux2 linux3'
U-Boot>
U-Boot> setenv ipaddr
U-Boot>
U-Boot> setenv serverip
U-Boot>
U-Boot> setenv resetuser
U-Boot>
U-Boot> run bootlinux
BCM5241A PHY Detected
waited 1680 msec
End of Autonegotiation
TFTP from server ; our IP address is 
Filename 'kernel.latest'.
Load address: 0x20cfffc0
Loading: #################################################################
         ########################################################
done
Bytes transferred = 1764880 (1aee10 hex)
TFTP from server ; our IP address is ---
Filename 'initrd.latest'.
Load address: 0x206fffc0
Loading: #################################################################
         #################################################################
         ##################################
done
Bytes transferred = 2405916 (24b61c hex)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 20cfffc0 ...
   Image Name:   WLNN_9G20_4.99
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1764816 Bytes =  1.7 MB
   Load Address: 20d00000
   Entry Point:  20d00000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Comment: *"Kernel comes up without UART, I think,..."* -- Not likely, that's wishful thinking.  *"So just default device tree files with older form of UART settings in board files."* -- There is a **.dtsi** file for your SoC, but no **.dts** file for that Atmel EK board.  So what *"default"* files are you using?  Did you append the DT blob to the kernel, since the boot log indicates that you don't explicitly load it?  It's trivial to enable the DBGU port for the console, so why do you still use a board file?

Comment: BTW your edits turns the meaning of the boot log into nonsense.  E.G. a `setenv ipaddr` command  would make a subsequent TFTP transfer impossible.

Comment: @sawdust - edited to delete the corporate ip addresses.

Comment: @sawdust - this is really my first bring up effort. I am still getting familiar with many things. I thought there would be some device tree that came with 4.4 kernel and got built by default. From your comment it looks like my statement on default device tree is wrong. No, I havent appended a DT blob nor was I aware that I had to generate the **.dts**. I will look into pulling/generating it, though not sure how at this point. Also are you suggesting by saying *"wishful thinking"* that the kernel is stuck much before it can even bring up the UART?